# Problema de envio de e-mail como Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um site onde na página principal ele possui uma seção com um formulário.
Esse formulário é para registrar e-mails para envio de newsletters. As demais páginas do site também possuem outros formulário e todas funcionam corretamente, exceto essa página principal.

#### COMO É O FUNCIONAMENTO?

É a forma mais simples possível. Há 2 campos input (Nome e E-mail) e 1 botão de enviar, conforme podem ver abaixo.

```
<section id="newsletter" class="newsletter bg-newsletter text-center">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="form-inline">
            <span class="newsletter-text">RECEBA NEWSLETTERS</span>
            <form id="formNewsLetter" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <input type="hidden" name="Acao" value="NewsLetter">
                <input type="hidden" name="adm_id" value="200">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-inline" name="nome" value="" placeholder="Nome">
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-inline" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail">
                <button type="submit" class="btn-newsletter">ENVIAR</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Ao clicar em **"Enviar"**, o submit é ativado e tem uma função `javascript/jquery` que processa os dados através do `AJAX`. Daí em diante, os dados chegam no arquivo `.PHP` e então funciona o procedimento de envio. Veja o código `javascript` abaixo:

```
$("#formNewsLetter").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#formNewsLetter").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://urldosite.com/sistema/Funcoes.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            if(response.indexOf("alert-success") > -1){
                $("#formNewsLetter").html("<br><div class='alert alert-success'><strong>SUCESSO!</strong> Email cadastrado com êxito!</div>");
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });

});
```

#### O QUE É O PROBLEMA?

O problema aqui é quando os dados **"saem do formulário para irem serem processados no código javascript"**. Quando eu clico em **"Enviar"**, a página redireciona e os dados do formulário ficam lá na `URL` do site, conforme abaixo:

```
http://urldositeprincipal.com.br/?Acao=NewsLetter&adm_id=200&nome=Lougans&email=lougans99%40mail.com
```

**OBS:** *Esse link é de um teste que eu fiz e enviei, então aparece isso na `URL` do navegador*;

#### O QUE JÁ TENTEI

- Enviar através do `method` e do `action` do `<form>` (funciona
  certinho);
   Olhar o devConsole (não exibe erros aparentemente);

#### O QUE TENHO CERTEZA DO QUE NÃO É O PROBLEMA

- Não é problema no arquivo `.PHP` que envia o e-mail;

É isso. Eu preciso da ajuda de vocês para entender o que está havendo. Já passei por algo assim antes mas o erro era bem claro, mas ao que parece isso ocorreu do nada. Até quarta-feira estava funcionando corretamente e agora isso começou a ocorrer apenas nesse formulário. O resto está completamente funcional.

**NOTA:** *Eu adoraria que as respostas fossem em parte orientações sobre o problema identificado quanto também (isso pode vir depois e se você se sentir tranquilo em fazer isso) uma explicação desse comportamento (eu sei que é entre a minha página `HTML` e o `Javascript`.*

Se precisarem de qualquer outra informação relevante para ajudar vocês na compreensão do meu problema, eu vou ficar feliz de editar a pergunta e acrescentar esses dados.

O meu **MUITO OBRIGADO** a todos que me ajudarem na resolução desses meus problemas!!!

Comment: Esse comportamento é incomum, já que vc está usando preventDefault pra cancelar o submit do form. Deve ter outro código influenciando nisso.

Comment: @Sam Pois é. Eu também pensei a mesma coisa.. única parte que eu não mexi ainda é no `success:`

Comment: Mas é como eu falei: deve ser outra coisa. Se vc criar uma página só com esse código aí vc verá que isso não acontece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Resolução do Problema - *Resposta do Autor*

Obrigado pelos comentários anteriores que me ajudaram a vasculhar alguma outras coisas até achar a solução.

Em suma, o `success:` do `AJAX` estava dando o problema. Eu acredito que seja porque o código abaixo não continha um ***valor > -1***

```
(response.indexOf("alert-success") > -1)
```

Eu modifiquei o `success:` criando outra mensagem de retorno similar. Confira como ficou:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#formNewsLetter").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"https://hecato.com/sistema/Ativacao.php",
                type:'POST',
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                success:function(){ //ESSE É O NOVO SUCCESS
                    $("#formNewsLetter").html("<br><div class='alert alert-success'><strong>SUCESSO!</strong> Email cadastrado com êxito!</div>"); //
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Bom, era isso. Agradeço aí pessoal. :)

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, o form está "submitando" os dados.
Um primeiro teste que eu faria, seria substituir o type="submit" do botão por type="button", assim o html vai ignorar que ele é um botão do tipo submit.
De resto, seu código parece correto.
Outro detalhe... Acredito que ao receber o retorno dos dados do seu backend, você irá precisar aplicar o método [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) para ter acesso ao retorno como se fosse um objeto. Com isso fica mais fácil trabalhar e manusear as infos.

Teste isso e diz pra gente se funcionou.

Comment: Opa mano. Foi mal, mas eu tentei e não deu certo, o problema persiste. Vou continuar avaliando e o Sam ali em cima me deu uma dica/ideia.

Answer (score 1):

Coloca o prevent defaut no final e adiciona tambem um `return false` so pra garantir

```js
$("#formNewsLetter").submit(function(event){
    var data = $("#formNewsLetter").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://urldosite.com/sistema/Funcoes.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            if(response.indexOf("alert-success") > -1){
                $("#formNewsLetter").html("<br><div class='alert alert-success'><strong>SUCESSO!</strong> Email cadastrado com êxito!</div>");
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
    
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="newsletter" class="newsletter bg-newsletter text-center">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="form-inline">
            <span class="newsletter-text">RECEBA NEWSLETTERS</span>
            <form id="formNewsLetter" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <input type="hidden" name="Acao" value="NewsLetter">
                <input type="hidden" name="adm_id" value="200">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-inline" name="nome" value="" placeholder="Nome">
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-inline" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail">
                <button type="submit" class="btn-newsletter">ENVIAR</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Mano, muito obrigado pela ajuda mas não resolveu o problema, o erro continuava. Agora a pouco a menos de 20 minutos consegui resolver e me deixou um pouco irritado com o que ocorreu. Eu não entendi os detalhes técnicos do problema mas era ali no Success, aquele retorno estava dando um conflito de alguma forma que não acionava corretamente a funcão. Obrigado pelo tempo que dispos para comentar uma resposta aqui :)